# search an element in XML

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to show by console the result of a search with LINQ, when debugging I find that the query works, but I do not know how to show the result

I have class XMLReader where I load the xml file, I read it and I do the query

```
class XMLReader
    {

            public  List<airlines> leerXML() 
            {            
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the airline you wish to search: ");
                string name;
                name= Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                if (nombre == "V"){
                XElement info = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Backup Files\data.xml");
                IEnumerable<XElement> airlines =
                    from el in info.Elements("airline")
                    where (string)el.Element("name") == "HK"
                    select el;
                foreach (XElement el in airlines)
                    Console.WriteLine((string)el.Attribute("origin"));



            }            

                return null;
            }

    }
```

then I have the Program class where I will show the information with a Console.WriteLine ();

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("show information: " ??????);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

here is the xml

```
<airlines>
    <airline id="01">
        <name>Viva Colombia</name>
        <origin>BOG</origin>
        <destination>MDE</destination>
        <date>01/03/2019</date>
    </airline>
    <airline id="02">
        <name>HK Express</name>
        <origin>BOG</origin>
        <destination>CTG</destination>
        <date>01/03/2019</date>
    </airline>
    <airline id="03">
        <name>Volotea</name>
        <origin>PEI</origin>
        <destination>BOG</destination>
        <date>01/03/2019</date>
    </airline>
    <airline id="04">
        <name>Vueling</name>
        <origin>MDE</origin>
        <destination>BOG</destination>
        <date>01/03/2019</date>
    </airline>
</airlines>
```

Comment: can you show how does xml look like?

Comment: what do you want to see in console after show information: ... the same as in `airlines` array?

Comment: did you try to use `(string)el.Attribute("origin").Value` instead of `(string)el.Attribute("origin")`

Comment: @IvanSalo this error comes out "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you correctly I guess you need to change your leerXML() method.
It will print origin where name is like you entered.
Please add null reference check where it is needed.

```
    public void leerXML()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the airline you wish to search: ");
        string name;
        name = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            XElement info = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Backup Files\data.xml");

            var airlines = info.XPathSelectElements("airline");
            foreach (XElement el in airlines)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Element("name").Value) && ((string)el.Element("name").Value).IndexOf(name) >= 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((string) el.Element("origin").Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }


 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XMLReader xmlReader = new XMLReader()
        xmlReader.leerXML(); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

First of all add the construcror to class XMLReader, so it looks like this:

```
public class XMLReader
{
        public XMLReader()
        {
        }

        public  List<airlines> leerXML() 
        {            
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the airline you wish to search: ");
            string name;
            name= Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            if (nombre == "V"){
            XElement info = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Backup Files\data.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> airlines =
                from el in info.Elements("airline")
                where (string)el.Element("name") == "HK"
                select el;
            foreach (XElement el in airlines)
                Console.WriteLine((string)el.Attribute("origin"));
          }            
            return null;
          }

  }
```

You already printing the xml in leerXML()
Just call it in your Main(string[] args)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XMLReader xmlReader = new XMLReader()
        xmlReader.leerXML(); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

That's it.

Comment: yes this should work if the foreach outputs values correctly. I guess there should be `(string)el.Attribute("origin").Value`

Comment: Yes, agree.I didn't even look to that part (:

Comment: @kryp when you add "public" to the XMLReader class. I have an error in public  List<airlines> !!!!leerXML()!!!!  "Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'List <airlines>' is less accessible than method 'XMLReader.LeerXML ()"

Comment: do: 
`public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XMLReader xmlReader = new XMLReader()
            xmlReader.leerXML(); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }`

Comment: @kryp i add"public class Program" but i still the same problem in the public  List<airlines> !!!!leerXML()!!!!!

Comment: Do you have XMLReader public? Please make the class also public, I might forgot to add it

Comment: Also, looks like main is not public, check, it should be: 'public static void Main(string[] args)'

Comment: List<airlines> is not correct type. It won't ever work. Linq is incorrect too. nombre is not initialized. It won't event build.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void ReadXmlFile()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"xmlfiledados.xml");
        XElement element = doc.Element("airlines").Descendants("airline").Where(a => a.Element("name").Value.Equals("HK Express")).First();

        Console.WriteLine(element.Element("name").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(element.Element("origin").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(element.Element("destination").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(element.Element("date").Value);
    }
```